# Linear Fractional Transformation from $R_{\infty} \rightarrow R_{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis

When constructing a proof for the general mapping of linear fractional transformations that maps a circle ($|z|=1$) onto itself, there are three stages: (A) construct a mapping from circle $\rightarrow$ to real domain $R_{\infty}$ (B) generic mapping from $R_{
\infty} \rightarrow R_{\infty}$ then inverse it back to a circle. The whole transformation is $S^{-1} \Phi S(z)$

Unit circle to $R_{\infty}$ has the form:

$$S(z) = -i \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

For $\Phi$, I am a bit confused. I can not multiply by a complex, because that would not garuneeted a mapping to the reals. I can muliply by a real constant $A$ Furthermore, I can "shift" by adding with a constant $B$.

$$\Phi(z) = Az + B$$

However, the proof in the textbook proceeds to define an arbitrary fractional transformation $(az+b)/(cz+ d)$, which I presume $a,b,c,d \in R$. Can I consider the two transformation equivalent? dividing by $z$ is not included in my transformation, and I am confused on how that preserves real to real transformation.

Comment: The Mobius transformations that take the reals to the reals are $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  where $ad-bc \neq 0.$   If that fails you have a constant mapping, all to one point. Next: the inverse mapping of  $\frac{pz+q}{rz+s}$ is     $\frac{sz-q}{rz-p},$   all with the same $ps-qr \neq 0$   Write your $S(z)$  in this p,q,r,s way to find its inverse. And, of course, multiplying or dividing both top and bottom of the fraction does not change the mapping.

Comment: Will Mobius transformations still map to the reals even if $a,b,c,d$ are in the complex plane?

Comment: no.  The traditional thing is to check what happens to the three points $0,1,\infty$ of the real line; we also  demand that $a$   be real, also (if $a=0$ )  then $b$ is real. We can do this by multiplying  top and bottom by $\bar{a}$  if that is nonzero, otherwise $\bar{b} $   With these restrictions and the images of $0,1, \infty $ all real, what about the rest of the coefficients in $ \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\; ? \; \;$  Meanwhile, you say scientist so you know matrices, the composition of two Mobius transformations has coefficient matrix given by the product of the two given coefficient matrices.

Comment: Ah ok. I pick $(0, 1, \infty)$ and map to $(p,q,r)$ all being real to construct this transformation from real line to real line... When I work out the algebra, there are restrictions on what $a,b,c,d$ can be producing the arbitrary transformation? I am just doing biological imaging - with a side interest in math.

Comment: and $\infty$  maps to $\infty$  when $c=0,$  otherwise to $\frac{a}{c}.$